# Binding Background (color) for the entire row of a telerik:GridViewDataControl WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, binding, telerik-grid

I have the following class:

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public enum Severity { Error, Warning}

    public ErrorMessage(Severity severity, string description) 
    {
        this.severity = severity;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Severity severity { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string background
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.severity)
            {
                case Severity.Error: return "Red";
                case Severity.Warning: return "Yellow";
                default: throw new Exception("severity out of bounds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am binding a List of ErrorMessage to a telerik GridViewDataControl WPF control:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataControl Margin="0" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office_Silver" Name="errorsGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ShowGroupPanel="False">
    <telerik:GridViewDataControl.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsReadOnly="True" UniqueName="{x:Null}" Header="Severity" DataMemberBinding="{Binding severity}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsReadOnly="True" UniqueName="{x:Null}" Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding description}" />
    </telerik:GridViewDataControl.Columns>
</telerik:GridViewDataControl>
```

I would like the entire Background color of each row to be bound to by the ErrorMessage.background property.  How do I do this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another method is to use a RowStyle that has binding from your class.  To avoid having to use any converter or even an event, change your ErrorMessage code to something like this:

```
public SolidColorBrush background
{
    get
    {        
        switch (this.severity)
        {
            case Severity.Error: return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);                   
            case Severity.Warning: return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            default: throw new Exception("severity out of bounds");
        }
    }
}
```

And then add this resource:

```
        <Style x:Key="xGridViewRowStyle"
               TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding background}" />
        </Style>
```

And on RadGridView:

```
RowStyle="{StaticResource xGridViewRowStyle}"
```

Slightly different approach, but just tested it and it definitely works. :)

Comment: For Silverlight, you will need to do something like what this post says: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx

Comment: For Silverlight, you can do the binding inside of the RowStyle element:
`<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle><Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow"><Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background}" /></Style></telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>`